# What's the difference between cubic and 3-regular graph?? Is edge connectivity equal to low degree in cubic?

Tags: graph-theory

What's the difference between cubic and 3-regular graph?? Is edge connectivity equal to low degree in cubic ?

Comment: They mean the same thing so far as I know.

Comment: They are the same. Cubic means 3-regular.

Comment: "Cubic" and "3-regular" mean the same thing. I don't understand your second question.